# Split list of strings based on occurrence count

Tags: python

I have list of strings as input

```
str_list1 = ['e1:g1', 'e2:g1', 'e1:o1', 'e2:o1']

str_list2 = ['e1:o1', 'e2:g1']
```

expected outputs

```
str_list1_output = [e1, e2] [g1, o1]

str_list2_output = [e1] [o1] [e2] [g1]
```

I wrote below code but it is failing for str_list2

```
str_list1 = ['e1:g1', 'e2:g1', 'e1:o1', 'e2:o1']
str_list2 = ['e1:o1', 'e2:g1']
entities, properties = zip(*(s.split(":") for s in str_list1))
print(set(entities)) # {'e1', 'e2'}
print(set(properties)) # {'g1', 'o1'}
```

I have 2 questions:-

1. What is wrong in the code? Above code returning same output for str_list2 as well instead of 4 separate list "[e1] [o1] [e2] [g1]"
2. Can I use zip to generate 2 separate sets of entities and properties instead of converting list to set while printing it?

Comment: you're never actually counting anything right?

Comment: I don't understand how you are generating your expected outputs.  What algorithm are you using?  Why are they different?

Comment: Why do you expect 2 lists of 2 elements each for str_list1 and 4 lists of 1 element each for str_list2? What is the logic behind this expected result? Your code will never achieve that.

Comment: `Can I use zip...` - zip by itself will not do what you want.

Comment: Your expected outputs look like they came from different algorithms. Can you explain in words what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: there are 2 kinds of inputs - 1) str_list1 - every entity (e1, e2,..) pairing with every property (g1, o1,..) i.e. cartesian product so the expected output is to generate original lists from given list of entity and property 2) str_list2 - entities pairing with different properties so output should split them to different lists

Comment: What output would you expect for `str_list3 = ['e1:g1',  'e1:o1', 'e2:o1']`?

Comment: @constantstranger here is the expected output - [e1] [g1, o1]
[e2] [o1]

Comment: There is more logic in your process than just splitting, transposing and making sets - you expect different outcomes based on certain criteria. We aren't a code writing service, you need to make an attempt to code your process and build in the logic. When you get stuck come back and ask.

Comment: Its ok @wwii. I know stackoverflow is not code writing service. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an exact answer to your question (namely, why the code you have tried is not giving the result you want), but I believe the code below will give the desired result, and perhaps the insight needed to answer your question can be found here:

```py
str_list1 = ['e1:g1', 'e2:g1', 'e1:o1', 'e2:o1']
str_list2 = ['e1:o1', 'e2:g1']
str_list3 = ['e1:g1',  'e1:o1', 'e2:o1']

def foo(str_list):
    from collections import defaultdict
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for s in str_list:
        entity, property = s.split(":")
        dct[entity] += [property]
    for k in dct:
        dct[k] = tuple(dct[k])
    rdct = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in dct.items():
        rdct[v] += [k]
    L = []
    for k, v in rdct.items():
        L += [v, list(k)]
    print(L)
foo(str_list1)
foo(str_list2)
foo(str_list3)
```

Output:

```
[['e1', 'e2'], ['g1', 'o1']]
[['e1'], ['o1'], ['e2'], ['g1']]
[['e1'], ['g1', 'o1'], ['e2'], ['o1']]
```